# Avoiding the time window between CreateProcess and AssignProcessToJobObject

Tags: winapi, process

The recommended way to ensure that child processes are killed when the parent is killed is to put them in a Job object.  But if the parent process dies between the calls to CreateProcess and AssignProcessToJobObject, the child process lives on.  How can I eliminate this race condition?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CREATE_SUSPENDED` as one of the flags to the `dwCreationFlags` argument of `CreateProcess`.

[MSDN reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Then, use the thread handle returned in the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` structure to call `ResumeThread` after you have called `AssignProcessToJobObject`.

Pseudo-code with no error handling:

```
STARTUPINFO startUp;
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;

CreateProcess (NULL, /* whatever */, NULL, NULL, TRUE,
    CREATE_SUSPENDED | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP, NULL, NULL, 
    &startUp, &processInfo);

AssignProcessToJobObject(hJobObject, processInfo.hProcess);

ResumeThread (processInfo.hThread);
```

Comment: Your code guards against the child spawning more processes before you catch it in the job object, but if the parent dies just before AssignProcessToJobObject, the child leaks.

Answer (score 1):

You can synchronize with your slave application using named events:

- master creates named event Z
- master starts slave process
- slave process opens named event and waits for signaled state
- master process does the job object thing
- master process sets event Z
- slave object sees event Z set and proceeds with what it is supposed to do, or on timeout (if master process dies prior to assigning slave process to job object) just exits immediately

Comment: I don't write the child program, but CREATE_SUSPENDED, mentioned in another answer, has the same effect as your event.  MY problem is that the parent can die just after spawning the child and before adding it to the job object.

Comment: This way the child process terminates immediately if master process is killed before adding slave process to the job object.

Comment: I understand now.  Still this doesn't work for me because I'm calling a preexisting exe for my child.  I can't rewrite it to follow your protocol.

Comment: Also, something you might be missing: ["After a process is associated with a job, by default any child processes it creates using CreateProcess are also associated with the job."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#managing_processes_in_jobs). Having your master object a member of job object prior to creating a the slave process will force child to be a part of job object right from the start.

Comment: Sometimes Visual Studio or Windows assigned the parent process to a job already.  Before Windows 8, jobs could not nest, so children cannot always inherit the parent job.  The children may need a further limited job, also.